# is "learn about company" a appropriate way to imply the meaning of "get info"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

in the job interview, i would like to get some info about the company, such as, how many people in the department that i would join.

I could ask the interviewer like this

"how many people in your department?"

in this scenario, is "learn about company" a appropriate way? such as

"I would like to learn about your department"

Comment: There is already a good answer, but it does not mention that the question you wanted to ask is not grammatical. A grammatical English sentence  or sentence must have a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to English Language Learners. Yes, in a job interview it's appropriate to say

> I would like to learn about your department.

However, it wouldn't be a good idea to only say that because there is so much information to provide about a department that the interviewer won't have time to tell you everything and won't know which details are important to you. It would be best to then ask about the details you're interested in knowing. For instance:

> I would like to learn about your department. How many people are in it?

When that question has been answered you can easily ask one or two more specific questions.

> Thanks for that answer. And what is a normal day for the employees like?